# How to not repeat permutations of i and j in “i not equal to j” loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops, symmetric

An exhaustive  “i not equal to j” loop typically starts out as

```
for i in range(t):
    for j in range(t):
        if i is not j:
```

To avoid repeating symmetric results (i.e. any `i with j` just gives the same answer as `j with i`), how can we additionally skip over these permuted instances in the loop above?

Comment: Did you know that you can specify a start *and* and end with `range`?

Comment: Please also include the sample input pair and desired output pairs?

Comment: `if i!=j` i not equal to j

Comment: Consider using `for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(t), 2):` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(t):
    for j in range(i, t):
        if i != j:
```

This guarantees that j >= i, so, therefore, there will be no i with j and j with i duplicates.

Alternatively,

```
for i in range(t):
    for j in range(i + 1, t):
```

Will exclude i j  combinations where i == j, as j > i